# Use etag compare and save with R curl::multi_download()

Tags: r, curl, etag

I'm processing some large files that I download. However, the files can be updated after some time and I need to run the analysis again. The problem is that the file provider does not warn if the file was updated. So I have to download it to check.

I saw that I could use curl --etag-save and --etag-compare to check if the file has changed before downloading.

Does R `curl::multi_download()` support etag cache? Or would it be better to use a combination of `system()` call with the `curl` command? Any other options?